# How to keep repetition out in user-defined functions

Tags: c

After compiling, my GetInt function causes the printf statements within the function to be printed on the screen three times. I believe this was caused when I initialized all radius, base, and height to GetInt(void) but I see no other way of accurately initializing those variables. Please help!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PI 3.14159
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int GetInt(void);
double CalcTriangleArea(int base, int height);
double CalcCircleArea(int radius);

int main(void)
{
    int radius, base, height;
    double triangleArea;
    double circleArea;

    radius = GetInt();
    base = GetInt();
    height = GetInt();
    triangleArea = CalcTriangleArea(base, height);
    circleArea = CalcCircleArea(radius);

    return(0);
}

int GetInt(void)
{
    int x;

    {
        printf("Please enter a radius: \n\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        printf("Please enter a base: \n\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        printf("Please enter a height: \n\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
    return(x);
}

double CalcTriangleArea(int base, int height)
{
    double triangleArea;
    printf("Triangle area is %.2f \n\n", triangleArea = .5*base*height);

    return(0);
}

double CalcCircleArea(int radius)
{
    double circleArea;
    printf("Area is %.4f \n\n", radius, circleArea = PI * pow(radius, 2));

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are writing to the same local variable `x` over and over...  Also, there is an unnecessary block `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule of thumb is to avoid repeating yourself whereever possible and don't repeat yourself. Imagine you want to change from two new lines (`\n\n`) to three  (`\n\n\n`)? You would need to make that change three times.

Looking at the bare bones of `GetInt`, you are printing a prompt, two new lines, get a value and returning it. Thus, we can write the new function like this:

```
void getInt(char* prompt)
{
    int x, numberOfConversions;               // numConversions is the number of int's read from the keyboard buffer

    printf("%s: \n\n", prompt);
    numberOfConversions = scanf("%d", &x);

    while (numberOfConversions != 1)          // while the user did not enter a number
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        numberOfConversions = scanf("%d", &x)"
    }

    return x;                                 // Always returns a valid number
}
```

Comment: Avoid reuse?  Please explain.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for point that out, I meant "avoid repeating yourself", reusablity is of course the goal here, so I kinda said the completely wrong thing xD I fixed my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

`GetInt` asks for, and reads, 3 distinct values, yet returns only the last one, every time it is called.

I think what you really want is to have `GetInt` ask for and return just 1 value, either passing it the prompt to print or printing it before calling it.